# How to get PHP variable from private function

Tags: php, oop

How can I get the variable $components out of this class and private function:

```
class WPCF7_Mail {
    private function compose() {

        return $components;
    }
}
```

This is my best attempt:

```
class test extends WPCF7_Mail {
    function compose( $send = true ) {
        global $components;
    }
}

new test();
global $components;
echo $components;
```

But I keep getting:

> Fatal error: Call to private WPCF7_Mail::__construct() from invalid
>   context

Edit: I cannot modify the class WPCF7_Mail. So I cannot make the function compose public.

Comment: Private methods can only be called from within the class that maintains it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, RhapX. Is there is no way to get a variable out from that example?

Comment: I don't know what it is you're trying to do, but theoretically you could change it to a `public function` in the `WPCF7_Mail class`, set `$components` to `$this->components` and it would work. I highly, highly advise against that. Methods have different visibilities for a reason.

Comment: Am I getting downvoted because this is not possible or because of the way I asked the question?

Comment: can you copy the code for the private method into a class that extends it.

Comment: I'm sorry @ArtisiticPhoenix, what are you asking?

Comment: Don't use the private scope if it doesn't suit your use/need. Change it to public if you desperately need the variable from this function.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, I cannot change it to public. That is my question, what other options are there?

Comment: Well, I would say you make a new function (in the class which extends the WPCF7 class) and with this function you call the private function and return the value. I don't really know what the private function does, so that's all what I can suggest.

Comment: That's not really true, you can "call" them from outside, too @RhapX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the private property or call a private function by using [ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php) and [Closure::bind()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php).

Make sure that WPCF7_Mail is in the same Namespace, otherwise you'll need to provide the full namespace name (e.g `'\Full\Namespace\WPCF7_Mail'`).

If you don't have a private/protected constructor with required parameters, you can simply use the class and `Closure::bind()`.

```
$class = (new ReflectionClass('WPCF7_Mail'))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
$getter = function ($a) {
    return $a->components;
};
$getter = Closure::bind($getter, null, $class);
var_dump($getter($class));
```

If you need to call the function, you can do it like this:

```
 $class = (new ReflectionClass('WPCF7_Mail'))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
 $getter = function ($a) {
    return $a->compose();
 };
 $getter = Closure::bind($getter, null, $class);
 var_dump($getter($class));
```

Note that this will work starting with php version 5.4